# How to select multiple values from a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have Users,Questions & Answers Table. A User can Post a question and can tag himself as well as the question upto 5 tags(eg:sql,java,html...). 
Do I need a separate table for Tags? if so how do I select tags from TAGS table for User and Questions posted by User.

Answer (score 0):

How are the tags stored? Comma-delimited data? There are ways to make it work but I would advise against storing them that way.

Whether you need a separate table for tags depends on whether you want to limit users and their questions to certain tags. If users are free to enter whatever tags they like, then no, you don't need a separate table for tags (unless maybe you want to save frequently-used tags or something like that).

I would strongly advise that you have separate tables for user tags and question tags rather than storing multiple tags in a single column in the user or question table.